# I keep getting "the page isn't working" when trying to use a prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I have a form on (login.php) which redirects to checkLogin.php where I want to check the username and password (entered from login.php) via prepared statements then send the user to my index page.

I have checked the connection ($connection) and that the vars are passed and working and hashed the PW using 'sha256' before checking it on DB ($myusername and $hashedPassword)
No matter what I do all I get when I enter the simplest of prepared statement is "HTTP error 500" as soon as I put in the code (below from checklogin.php)

```
//THIS QUERY WORKS
//$query = "SELECT users_id, username, password, user_type, validUser, expires FROM copyright_users WHERE username = '$myusername' AND password = '$hashedPassword'";
//$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//THIS DOES NOT WORK EVEN THOUGH IS IT REALLY SIMPLE
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT users_id FROM copyright_users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $myusername);

$stmt->execute();

//$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: what does the php error log reveal about the actual error? In the query that works you use `$connection` but the one that failes uses `$dbConnection`

Comment: try this `$stmt->bind_param($myusername);`